# How to call function from MongoDB in Meteor.js?

Tags: meteor

I would like to call functions that I have defined in MongoDB with Meteor.js?
For example I have a function call `hi()` in MongoDB.
To call it in MongoDB I use this command:

```
> db.eval('hi()')
```

What about in Meteor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var funcInputObj={};var mongoFuncName='testfunc';
 MongoInternals.defaultRemoteCollectionDriver().mongo.db.eval('db.loadServerScripts();return ' + mongoFuncName+ '(' + JSON.stringify(funcInputObj|| {}) + ');',function (err, mongoFuncReturnData) {


   console.log(mongoFuncReturnData);
 });
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: Returns `null` in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Unless someone contradicts me it is not possible yet.
Meteor doesn't let you "play" with all Mongo functions.

There are some tracks you can read and dig [here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/532).

I wish I could have helped you more, good luck.

Comment: thanks for your help. I will try to search for more solutions.